# Map.prototype.set returns with undefined in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, react-css-modules

I'm trying to build a react application, and use react-css-modules. Everything runs fine under FF and Chrome, but in IE11 I encounter the following issue, at page loading I get the following exception message:

*Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference*

It seems that the issue occurs in [generateAppendClassname](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/blob/master/src/generateAppendClassName.js) (line 37) of the react-css-modules, where the *stylesIndexMap* will remain undefined. It seems that the following operation will set undefined for the Map.

`stylesIndexMap = stylesIndex.set(styles, new _simpleMap2.default());`

In theory Map.set should return with the map itself even under IE11, could somebody help to understand the problem?

Comment: You are on the wrong way. This code doesnt use standard maps, they implemented their own (imported at the top of the file). Your error is somewhere else

Comment: Sorry my bad, it indeed uses the builtin Map if present

Comment: You will have to find a workaround and maybe submit a bug report. The web is full of issues like this unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to do that, maybe i can force somehow the usage of SimpleMap.

Comment: The problem with simple map is that it is much slower. The best would be just not to rely on this "set returns the map" thing. (it is a bad javascript feature anyway, because one could argue that not the map but the set value should be returned, so it is ambigous)

Comment: Seems that IE11 does not support yet the Map.prototype.set returns this functionality. Thank you for your help I opened an issue regarding the usage of the Map.set(), till the fix maybe I can just run through the .js on babel and get an ES5 source, I do not know yet whether that is a viable option or not.